# What's exactly the difference between "per se" and "ipso facto"?

Tags: word-usage

These two seem quite interchangeable—is it so or is it just me unable to comprehend the difference?

Comment: Don't forget _prima facie_ which also has a similar but subtly different meaning in legal contexts.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller  *Prima facie* - 'at first appearance' - slightly different to 'the fact alone' - I think. *There is prima facie evidence of murder, in the form of a smoking gun; but possession of a smoking gun is not ipso facto evidence of guilt*

Comment: Technically, [this belongs here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language) then : ))

Comment: @moonwave99 Does it? I think the thrust of the OP's question is about the usage of _per se_ and _ipso facto_ in English, primarily in academic and legal English, and I threw _prima facie_ into the mix as another possible candidate with a similar meaning.  I think the discussion involves Latin only incidentally; the important thing is how the two (or three) terms are used in English, even if borrowed unchanged from the Latin.  (It's kind of analogous to arguing about whether _chaise lounge_ is incorrect—that wouldn't belong in a hypothetical French SE but here.)

Comment: @WS2 Great example of _prima facie_ vs _ipso facto_ in legal English.  I'd like to see this expanded into a separate question and answer.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller of course, I was just amused that we may soon have a latin Stackexchange site : ))

Answer (score 14):

The meanings are close, but I think the main difference is the context in which each is used.

***Per se***, meaning 'in itself' is used in sentences such as this, from the OED:

*1992   New Republic 13 July 4/3   Real conservatives do not reject homosexuality per se (in itself) so much as they reject victimology.*

***Ipso facto*** meaning 'the fact itself', or 'the fact alone' tends to be used by lawyers in statements such as:

*Possession of a vehicle's registration document is not ipso facto (by that fact alone) evidence of ownership*.

The word *fact* looks like the obvious English translation of *facto*, but it doesn't quite capture the meaning of the Latin. The root is the verb *facere* which means *to do* or *to make*. So *factum* literally means *a/the thing that is/was done/made*. The English word "fact" also includes more abstract ideas. "All triangles have three sides" is a *fact* in English, but not really a *factum* in Latin.

Comment: It seems that **per se** might've been used in the second example as well—"Possession of a vehicle's registration document is not **per se** evidence of ownership" (I'm not sure what place in the sentence it should take, though) . Is it so or am I just imagining things?

Comment: The meaning "in itself" is a reasonable equivalent English phrase, but it doesn't express the wide range of meaning of "per" in Latin very clearly. The relevant meanings of "per" in this context express *means* - "through / by / by means of / with / by way of itself" or *causation* - "because of / on account of itself". More explanatory translations of "ipso facto" (which is in the Ablative case) would be "by means of the fact itself" or "because of the fact itself".

Comment: @D4RKSOUL "Ipso facto" can only be applied to a *fact* (*ipsum factum* = *the fact itself*). "Per se" can by applied to any *thing* (*se* = *itself*) . A fact can be considered to be a thing. But in "Possession of a vehicle's registration document is not per se evidence of ownership" you would have to stop to decide if the *thing* that "per se" referred to is "the registration document" (wrong) or "Possession of the registration document" (right).

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand whether my use of **per see** in the example about "possession of the registration" was right. Can anyone answer?

Comment: @alephzero I will admit that I always think of *per se* as meaning *as such*, and I believe that is mostly how business people use it. You must understand that I have spent my life in a commercial environment, and am no Latin scholar, as you appear to be. In answer to DARKSOUL's comment point - you are probably right that *per se* could have been used in the second example. But *ipso facto* in my experience tends more to be used in legal documents whilst *per se* more in everyday business conversation.

Comment: It might be worth adding that *fact* looks like the obvious English translation of *facto,* but it doesn't quite capture the meaning of the Latin. The root is the verb *facere* which means *to do* or *to make*. So *factum* literally means *a/the thing that is/was done/made.* The English word "fact" also includes more abstract ideas. "All triangles have three sides" is a *fact* in English, but not really a *factum* in Latin.

Comment: @alephzero Thank you for that valuable contribution. Please feel free to edit my answer by including it.

Comment: @D4RKS0UL It's not "wrong", but (as I tried to explain) I think it is slightly ambiguous what the "per se" refers to. "The registration document per se does not name the *owner* of a vehicle" would be good, and unambiguous. (The registration document actually names the "registered keeper" of the vehicle, i.e., the person responsible for ensuring that it is *used* legally. It may be *owned* by somebody else, for example by the finance company which loaned you the money to buy it.)

Comment: @alephzero I see. I just didn't understand it for some reason. Of course I meant **per se**  to refer to "possession of the registration document". What place in this example would you suggest moving **per se** to in order to make it clear what it refers to? I have to admit I still can't understand the grammar behind these phrases (per se and ipso facto) since they're both adverbs but they're often separated from verbs they're supposed to modify.

Comment: @D4RKS0UL Adverbs and particularly adverb phrases can modify almost anything, not just verbs. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverb-phrases. They usually occur immediately before or after the words they modify. The commonest way to parse a sentence is to assume they modify the *smallest* phrase that makes sense, so in "... the r.d. per se ....", the "per se" modifies "r.d.". On the other hand in "... the r.d. ipso facto ...", *ipso facto* can only refer to a *fact*. "The r.d."  is a *thing*, not a fact, so *ipso facto* must refer to "*Possession* of the r.d."

Comment: @alephzero  Excellent stuff! Why don't you supply that as part of an answer. It should attract a lot of votes!

Comment: @D4RKS0UL  "What place in this example would you suggest moving per se to in order to make it clear what it refers to?" You could add some commas to suggest the correct parsing of the sentence: "Possession of a vehicle's registration document, per se, is not evidence of ownership."

Answer (score 3):

*Ipso facto* is used to present one fact as a reason for another, whereas *per se* is used to narrow a noun.

To expand upon the examples that WS2 offers:

- *ipso facto* relates vehicle registration to vehicle ownership.
- *per se* narrows homosexuality to exclude victimology. (Obviously I'm just using the example as given here.)

Answer (score 3):

The term **per se** means **the thing itself**, to the exclusion of anything implied, derived, construed, or represented. The very thing named.

> "It's not that I dislike cats *per se*. But I am allergic to them."

Lacking context, I would label this term "philosophical" in nature. (The nature of a thing.)

The term **ipso facto** implies a causality, one thing being named having another thing as a necessary consequence due to the first thing's existence.

> "The goods were found in his possession, *ipso facto* he was involved in *some* way."

(Bad example but I cannot come up with a better one right now.)

Lacking context, I would label this term "judicial" in nature. (The meaning / consequence of a thing.)

Answer (score 2):

People have said variations of this, but no one seems to have said clearly:

***Per se* refers to *things*, whereas *ipso facto* refers to *facts*. Things exist (or don't); facts are true or false.**

Look at all the examples provided:

- *Possession of a smoking gun is not* ipso facto *evidence of guilt.*

  - Possession is a fact: it is either true or false that the defendant possesses a smoking gun.
- *Real conservatives do not reject homosexuality* per se *(in itself) so much as they reject victimology.*

  - Homosexuality is a thing: it either exists or it doesn't.
- *That the delegates could come to an agreement indicates* ipso facto *that they acknowledged...*

  - Whether the delegates could come to an agreement is a fact: they either could or could not come to an agreement.
- *It's not that I dislike cats* per se. *But I am allergic to them.*

  - Cats are a thing: they either exist or don't.

I had to read this thread a few times over to get it.

Answer (score 1):

*Ipso facto* is less common in my experience and always has the meaning of 'in and of itself, without extraneous factors'. "That the delegates could come to an agreement indicates *ipso facto* that they acknowledged..."

*Per se* can also have this meaning, which is what it originally meant in Latin, but it is commonly used now to mean 'as expected, exactly, technically, as such'. "The witness didn't answer the question *per se*, but he did imply..."